# Using Generic Foreign Keys to retrieve data

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

I have the class `Streams` in my model.py which is supposed to have a generic foreign key to another class type (`Commentdata` or `ResponseData`)

When I get a Streams row I want to access the data in another class with the same id. For instance, when I create a Stream db entry it will also create a CommentData db entry with the same ID and the row will have a genericforeignkey to `CommentData`. When I want to access the comment data I will check the related class for that stream and then query the content type for rows where id = Stream.id

This is in my Streams class:

```
limit = models.Q(app_label='picture', model='commentdata') | models.Q(app_label='picture', model='responsedata')`

content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, verbose_name='Data Type', limit_choices_to=limit, null=True, blank=True)

object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name='Related Object', null=True, blank=True)

content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

In django admin I can save`Streams` content type to the either(`Commentdata` or `ResponseData`) which is fine.

If I do something along the lines of

```
x = Streams.objects.all()
y = x[0].content_type
```

I can output what class streams related to. I can't then do something like `y.objects.all()` to get the related class as I get the error

> Manager isn't accessible via ContentType instances

Is there anyway to use the ContentType Manager to find this information?  `ContentType.objects.get_for_model(x[0])` returns the class `Stream`. Similarly `ContentType.objects.get_for_model(y)` returns content type.

Thank you

Comment: I think you want to do this:

`x[0].__class__.objects.all()`

If I haven't misunderstood your question.

Comment: Didn't work for me unfortunately, it returned the objects from Streams and not commentdata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I see what you're doing. First, there is no way to do what you are trying to do using the content_types API. But it can be done.

As you stated:

```
x = Streams.objects.all() # all stream objects
y = x[0].content_type # CommentData ContentType object
```

So you need to use basic Django ORM like this:

```
from django.db.models.loading import get_model

x = Streams.objects.all() # all stream objects
y = x[0].content_type # CommentData ContentType object
model_class = get_model(app_label=y.app_label, model_name=y.model)

model_class.objects.all() # all objects of the type
```